# Entity Framework Execute Query on Multiple Servers

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I am developing my first C# web app , which needs to import data from multiple servers on demand.

I have the server names stored in a table (DataServer). So I need to connect to each server and run a query, the results of which I want to add to my data model.

This is what I currently have in my repository

```
public void ScanServer(int serverKey)
    {
        var serverName =  FindByKey(serverKey).ServerName;
        var sqlQuery = "SELECT name ,description FROM myTbl";

        Context.Database.SqlQuery<Names>(sqlQuery);
    }
```

I know using Context is incorrect, I'm hoping to replace that with the connection string held in my DataServer table.

The results then need to be added to my Names DataModel.

Am I on the right track with this?

Comment: It seems to me that you will need to have to create a DbContext per server and pass in the connection string (which should be fairly easy) and then you can do `Context.Database...` if you want some parallelism, you can do `sqlQueries.Add(SqlQuery<Names>(sqlQuery).ToListAsync())` and then do a `Task.WhenAll(sqlQueries)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to open a connection using a connection string thus:

```
foreach(string connectionString in Servers)
{
    using (var context = new DbContext(connectionString))
    {
      //Query code
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I've added the following
    var DataServerContext = new DbContext(serverName);
                {
                    DataServerContext.Database.SqlQuery<Names>(sqlQuery);
                }